# UWP speech synthesis without a XAML MediaElement

Tags: uwp, text-to-speech, c++-cx

Every UWP text-to-speech sample I can find uses a MediaElement control created with XAML. E.g., something like this, which works fine:

```
using namespace Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis;

//..........

void App::MainPage::buttonSpeak_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    create_task(synthesizer->SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(L"I am ready."))
        .then([this](SpeechSynthesisStream ^stream)
    {
        MediaElement ^media = mediaElement; //created in a separate XAML file
        media->AutoPlay = true;
        media->SetSource(stream, stream->ContentType);
        media->Play();
    });
}
```

How do I adapt it to work without a XAML-based interface (a holographic DirectX application, in my case)? I have tried creating a MediaElement programmatically, e. g. `MediaElement ^media = ref new MediaElement();`, it always throws `"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"` exception.

Comment: the documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with `MediaPlayer` instead of `MediaElement`.

```
using namespace Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis;
using namespace Windows::Media::Playback;

//...

SpeechSynthesizer ^synthesizer = ref new SpeechSynthesizer();
MediaPlayer ^player = ref new MediaPlayer();

//...
create_task(synthesizer->SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(L"I am ready."))
    .then([this](SpeechSynthesisStream ^stream)
{
    player->SetStreamSource(stream);
    player->Play();
});
```

It works, although the compiler gives a warning that `SetStreamSource` is deprecated, and `Source` should be used instead, but I haven't figured out how to use it.

Comment: My use case is quite similar but the audio playback is triggered via background task. The mediaplayer didn't seem to work in that case. My question is posted here if you can help me out with some pointers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750227/uwp-background-audio-not-working-when-switched-to-holographic-mode

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Headcrab's answer and use `Source` instead of `SetStreamSource`.

replace:

```
player->SetStreamSource(stream);
```

with:

```
player->Source = Windows::Media::Core::MediaSource::CreateFromStream(stream, stream->ContentType)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing the exception because `MediaElement` could work only on an UI thread.

You can use [`AudioGraph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs). It can run on any thread.